# Two different id's for retrieving draggable object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, pug, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this piece of code, which works perfectly in retrieving coordinates for an draggable object, however as you notice here:

```
$("#droppable").droppable({
accept: "#draggable, #draggable2",
```

I have two draggable objects, which will both get the id "benchdropped" + c, how would you suggest I could have different id's for each type of draggable object so later I can use that in pug, to retrieve it.
I mention everything else works, I am using NodeJS, PUG.
Here is the code:

```
''' $("#droppable").droppable({
    accept: "#draggable, #draggable2",


    drop: function(e, ui) {
    c++;
    var $obj = ui.helper.clone().attr('id', 'benchdropped' + c).draggable({
      stop : function (event, ui) {
      positions[this.id] = ui.position;
      console.log('positions', positions);
        // console.log(Object.keys(positions)); //ids for benches - to be used in node.
        
      }


    }); '''
```

Comment: you want #draggable to drop to benchdropped1,  #draggable2 to drop to benchdropped2?

Comment: No, so at this moment I have two objects Draggable and Draggable2, however I need to differentiate them when I save them in the database, at this point if I drag Draggable or Draggable2, the item gets an id benchdropped(i++), I need the id unique for each type of object (two objects). Eg. Drag Draggable first object creates an id benchdropped1, drag Draggable second object creates an id benchdropped2 and so on, for the second object Drag Draggable2 creates an id benchdropped_draggable2 and second item same object id benchdropped_draggable2_1 and so on